# How to make Gstreamer pipeline use GPU

Tags: video-streaming, gpu, gstreamer, nvidia, imx6

I am using below gstsreamer pipeline to stream camera on remote system,

gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=10 drop-on-latency=TRUE ! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink use-vsync=true

the remote system has NVIDIA GPU. We are looking for a way to reduce latency of streaming
video on remote display.
How we can have gst pipeline make use of GPU in order to accelerate the streaming.
Is there any plugin/element we can add in gstreamer pipeline to use GPU.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=10 drop-on-latency=TRUE ! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! glimagesink
```

The [GstGLImageSink](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/opengl/glimagesink.html?gi-language=c) renders frames using OpenGL. Internally, it will do HW accelerated color space conversion, if needed.